# JavaScript array sort not working in default Android browser

Tags: javascript, sorting, android-browser

I have a problem with the function listed below. On my PC this code is working perfectly, and on Chrome on my mobile phone too. However, when I run this code in the default Android browser the result is that the first 4 elements of the sorted array are not what they are supposed to be;

- Element 1: 0
- Element 2: 128
- Element 3: 256
- Element 4: 384

Now I am wondering why this is the case, up until where the array is sorted the values gathered are fine, after that, they are incorrect...

According to this link it should be compatible with the default Android browser:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Browser_compatibility

```
function sendWeekProgram() {
//Get all the info to send
var weekProgramData;
//Check if the week program is enabled
if($("#vacationMode").prop('checked') === false) {
    weekProgramData = '<week_program state="on">';
}else {
    weekProgramData = '<week_program state="off">';
}

//For each day get the switches
for(i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    //Set the day name
    switch(i) {
        case 0:
            dayName = "Monday";
            break;
        case 1:
            dayName = "Tuesday";
            break;
        case 2:
            dayName = "Wednesday";
            break;
        case 3:
            dayName = "Thursday";
            break;
        case 4:
            dayName = "Friday";
            break;
        case 5:
            dayName = "Saturday";
            break;
        case 6:
            dayName = "Sunday";
            break;
    }

    //Add the day to the query
    weekProgramData = weekProgramData + '<day name="' + dayName + '">';

    //Create an array
    var arraySwitches = [];

    //Put all day switches in an array
    for(j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        //Check if the switch is on or off
        if(($("#daySwitch" + dayName + (j + 1)).hasClass("dayOverViewTextActive") === false) || ($("#nightSwitch" + dayName + (j + 1)).hasClass("dayOverViewTextActive") === false)) {
            arraySwitches[j] = {type: 'day', state: 'off', value: parseInt($("#daySwitch" + dayName + (j + 1)).text().replace(":", ""))};
        }else {
            arraySwitches[j] = {type: 'day', state: 'on', value: parseInt($("#daySwitch" + dayName + (j + 1)).text().replace(":", ""))};
        }
    }

    //Put all night switches in an array
    for(j = 5; j < 10; j++) {
        //Check if the switch is on or off
        if(($("#daySwitch" + dayName + (j-4)).hasClass("dayOverViewTextActive") === false) || ($("#nightSwitch" + dayName + (j-4)).hasClass("dayOverViewTextActive") === false)) {
            arraySwitches[j] = {type: 'night', state: 'off', value: parseInt($("#nightSwitch" + dayName + (j-4)).text().replace(":", ""))};
        }else {
            arraySwitches[j] = {type: 'night', state: 'on', value: parseInt($("#nightSwitch" + dayName + (j-4)).text().replace(":", ""))};
        }
    }

    //Sort the array
    arraySwitches.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.value
             - b.value;
    });

    //For each element in the array, add it to the weekProgramData
    for(k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
        //Add leading zeroes
        arrayValue = arraySwitches[k].value.toString();
        while(arrayValue.length < 4) {
            arrayValue = "0" + arrayValue;
        }

        //First convert the integer back to the time
        time = arrayValue.substr(0,2) + ':' + arrayValue.substr(2);

        //Add value to weekprogram
        weekProgramData = weekProgramData + '<switch type="' + arraySwitches[k].type + '" state="' + arraySwitches[k].state + '">' + time + '</switch>';
    }

    //Add the closing tag of the day
    weekProgramData = weekProgramData + '</day>';
}

//Add the closing tag of the week program
weekProgramData = weekProgramData + '</week_program>';

//Send the info
putInfo("weekProgram", weekProgramData);
}
```

Comment: In case it works in all other cases try putting  return a.value
             - b.value; in one line. Better yet minify.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not solve the problem.